# Can I highlight let scoping issues with ESlint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I went through an enormous, sloppily-written code base and blindly did a `s/var/let/g`. In a couple of occasions, I was able to spot "re-definitions" of variables, now declared with `let`, but they were causing no particular trouble.

In one situation, I had something like this:

```
let c = '';

if (d.colour) {
    c = d.colour;
} else {
    let rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    let c = 'hex-' + d.subject + rand;
    // ...
}

$(this).attr('class', c);
```

Line 7 is the offending bit. Once I removed that `let`, the value was correctly assigned and everything went back to normal.

This sounds to me like something that a static analyser should be able to catch, and yet ESlint didn't say a thing. Is there a particular rule I can enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider to enable ESlint `no-shadow`, this rule aims to eliminate shadowed variable declarations and it would warn you on the second `c` declaration.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow

Comment: HA. You were quicker than me going through the list of rules, I was like "what is this `no-shadow` thing?" and then came back here and found your answer :)